# Next.js dynamic route parameter is undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

### The problem

In my Next.js app I want to use the value of a dynamic route to fetch some html via http and use the result on the page.

For example, the Next route

`/test`

should result in an http request to

`https://blobstorage.com/test.html`

The issue I have is that when I make the api call, the route value is `undefined` so I end up making a http request to `https://blobstorage.com/undefined.html`

Note: To be clear here, **the issue is that the value is not available at the point I render the page**. **This question is not asking how I can get the value from the router.**

### Code example

```
export default function Home() {

  const [html, setHtml] = useState('')
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {

    const { url } = router.query

    setHtmlText(url)
    
    async function setHtmlText(htmlUrl) {
      const result = await fetch(`https://blobstorage.com/${htmlUrl}.html`)
      const htmlText = await result.text()
      setHtml(htmlText);
    }
  }, [])

  function createMarkup() {
    return {__html: html};
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {html && <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} ></div>}
    </div>    
  )
}
```

I don't know how to render the page *only when the value from the route is available*. Could someone help me here please?

Comment: I suggest check router.query what includes or router. Write some console log for router look at which properties includes

Comment: I get the value but not by the time I want to use it. I tried to make that clear in the post but I will make an edit now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the page structure for dynamic routing like : url/[slug].js and get the router.query.slug once the parameter router.isReady is true.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if(router.isReady){
      const urlPath = router.query.slug;
      
      setHtmlText(urlPath)
    
    async function setHtmlText(htmlUrl) {
      const result = await fetch(`https://blobstorage.com/${htmlUrl}.html`)
      const htmlText = await result.text()
      setHtml(htmlText);
    }
    }
  }, [router.isReady]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How exactly should I have the component set up in the file system? I've tried `pages/[url].js`, `pages/url.js` and `pages/url/url.js` but all return a 404 when going to `/test` or `/url/test`

Comment: I wasn't able to understand the question clearly, previous answer was considering the static routes in pages folder, for dynamic routing I have updated the answer.